# Error with GhostScript and ImageMagick in Centos 6h

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I've using Ghostscript and ImageMagick for pdf to png conversion. PDF files are nothing but font file.

On some specific fonts like Avenir-BlackOblique, Avenir-BookOblique, Avenir-HeavyOblique etc.. (Fonts having suffix **Oblique**), I'm getting following error while converting to png.

---

> Error: /rangecheck in --run--
>   Operand stack:
>   --dict:6/15(L)-- --dict:13/15(ro)(L)-- 1 A -string-
>   Execution stack:
>   %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 1 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue %finish_show --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 9 10 1 --nostringval-- (gs_show_enum) %op_show_continue
>   Dictionary stack:
>   --dict:1155/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:21/40(L)-- --dict:7/15(L)--
>   Current allocation mode is local
>   GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>   convert: **Postscript delegate failed** `/var/www/smartmarketerca.pbsmartqa.pb.com/data/temp/32946b403f985cd25ee0fde2d309a17a/Avenir-HeavyOblique.pdf': No such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/611.
>   convert: missing an image filename`/var/www/smartmarketerca.pbsmartqa.pb.com/data/temp/daba4128fccab3d646f0980d91660c30/72e2e9945e37481977500d7fdbb00b00.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.

---

I'm using following configuration:

ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-01-30 Q16
GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

I tried to upgrade GhostScript to 9.15 but even though its giving same but bit other message:

---

> convert: **PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library 8.70]** -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-13460R723BggmiU56%d" "-f/tmp/magick-13460xmDYin8GYPzD" "-f/tmp/magick-13460gVQPulJIgS39"': Error: /rangecheck in --run--
>   Operand stack:
>   --dict:6/15(L)-- --dict:13/15(ro)(L)-- 1 A -string-
>   Execution stack:
>   %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 1 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue %finish_show --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 9 10 1 --nostringval-- (gs_show_enum) %op_show_continue
>   Dictionary stack:
>   --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:21/40(L)-- --dict:7/15(L)--
>   Current allocation mode is local
>   GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>   @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/271.
>   convert: no images defined`/var/www/smartmarketerca/data/temp/0d9e22bf29b00073cfeb51edd2f4d906/9d1f6dbc420b659b6f9489912061c540.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.

---

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: As noted in our own bug tracker, you first need to upgrade to 9.15 (and have IM use it). If the problem persists then we will need to see an example file and a Ghostscript command line. As I said in the bug tracker, I'm afraid I cannot help you with ImageMagick though, either getting it to use a more recent version of GS, or getting the GS command line. NB if you can get a command line you could try the conversion with GS from the shell ,and see if the current version works for you, at least.

Comment: Hi Ken, Issue is resolved now. Using rpm -e --nodeps ghostscript-8.70-19.el6.x86_64 command, I was able to remove ghostscript older version, as well as configuring ImageMagick with --gslib=no-- option, enforced IM to use gs program instead of gs package. That was the issue, since ImageMagick was built against the Ghostscript delegate library rather than the Ghostscript delegate program (i.e. gs), So by default it was always using 8.70 library instead of later version that I installed.

Comment: Ah thar's useful to know thanks. I did wonder about the gslib delegate as I'm not used to seeing that in ImageMagick but, sadly, I don't know enough about IM to dispense advice there. I'm glad its working for you now.